# QDial: how to pass int value to a Qfile that requires const char*?

Tags: c++, qt, qdial

Problem is already described in title: I'm using a `QDial` to set contrast level of a LCD 7" display (connected to an embedded Linux Single Board Computer).

Simple way to do this is to send on terminal an "echo" instruction. I send it as a QFile:

```cpp
QFile ContrLCD("/sys/class/backlight/backlight/brightness");
```

and I need to send the level writing in this `QFile`

```cpp
ContrLCD.write("number");
```

Problem is `QDial` manage `int` variable, while `QFile` requires `const char*` to send number corresponding to contrast.

How to do this?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Looks like it. After all you write strings to text files (even if implicit conversion takes place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is taken from the documentation for [`QFile`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfile.html):

> ```
> QFile file("out.txt");
> if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
>     return;
>
> QTextStream out(&file);
> out << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
> ```

Seems like you can use a `QTextStream` to write formatted output to a `QFile`. I did not use it myself, so there might be other ways, but for formatted output of numbers this seems to be the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
BacklightController::setBrightness(int brightness) // slot
{
    QFile f{"/sys/class/backlight/backlight/brightness"};
    if (!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) return;
    QTextStream stream{&f};
    stream << brightness;
}
```